# Responsive Slides - overlaps another div when resized

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, overlap, responsive-slides

Url - http://www.eden-lime-mortar.co.uk/index18.html

As the screen size is reduced (about the point it becomes a tablet potrait view) the responsive slide images overlap the div with the spry menu.

Using dreamweaver fluid grid and templates.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/2017.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="fluid/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="2017fluid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="2010copy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="fluid/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
         auto: true,  
         speed: 1500,
         timeout: 4000,  
         maxwidth: "500",
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="LayoutDiv1"><img src="images/Img_39211.jpg" alt="hot lime mortar" class="imgheader"></div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Hot Lime Mortar</a></li>
      <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hot Lime Mortar</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hydraulic Limes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Finishes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Eden Lime Insulation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Savolit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">NBT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Geocell</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pozzolan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Hot Lime Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Eden Lime Insulation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion1" -->
  <div id="leftcoltop">

  <ul class="rslides">
      <li><img src="slide1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide2.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide3.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide4.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide5.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide6.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide7.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide8.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide9.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide10.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="slide11.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>



  </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion5" -->
  <div id="toprightinfo">

   <span class="toprighthd">Eden Hot Lime Mortar </span><br>
    <span class="toprighthd">Manufacturer and Retailer
    of Hot Lime Mortar, Lime Putty 
  & Lime Insulation.<br>
  <br>
    </span>
  <span class="toprightp"> Call or Email Now to discuss how HLM can help your building project<br>
07717400233<br>
info@hotlimemortar.com</span>
  <p class="toprightp"><br>
  </p>

  </div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
  <div id="rightcolbody"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion2" -->EditRegion2<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
  <div id="fotter">
    <h3><img src="images/keim.gif" alt="Keim" border="0"><img src="products/GEOCELLLogo.png" alt="Geocell"><img src="products/pavatex.png" alt="pavatex"></h3>
    <h3>Hot Lime Mortar Ltd</h3>
    <p><strong>Manufacturer and Retailer of Hot Lime Mortar and Lime Putty</strong></p>
    <p>Edenholme, Great Musgrave, Kirkby Stephen, Cumbria, CA174DP<br>
      Tel:07717400233 Email: info@hotlimemortar.com<br>
      All Material on this site © Eden Lime Mortar</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->
</html>
```

CSS - used to edit style

```
html, body, ul, ol, li, p, h1, h2, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    list-style-image: url(none);
}


body {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 100.01%;
    background-image: url(images/backgroundwall.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {

}
.gridContainer.clearfix {
    background-color: #756e52;
}


#leftcol {
    background-color: #756e52;
}
#leftcoltop {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

/*right col is actually left n vice versa*/
#rightcolbody {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.floatright {
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #150B0A;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }

.hlmlogo {

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}

  .imgheader {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.imglogo {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#rightcol {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.toprighthd {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", serif;
    color: #FAF9ED;
    font-size: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.toprightp {
    color: #EBE8BD;
    font-size: 95%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", serif;
    font-size-adjust: 140%;
    color: #150B0A;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", serif;
    color: #372E25;
    font-size: 125%;
}
h3 {
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", serif;
    font-size: 125%;
    color: #8E8870;
}
h4 {
}
a {
    color: #A29B81;
}
p {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #594D35;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#fotter {
    text-align: center;
}
#fotter h3 {
    color: #B0AB8D;
}
#fotter p {
    color: #EEEEEC;
}
```

Can post the boilerplate css and fluid css if required?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To help other users answer your question, and to help future users learn from the answers can you please reduce this to a [Minimal verifiable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Is this(https://i.imgur.com/vupGUZF.png) how you want it to look when the screen size is reduced?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.MenuBarVertical` and `.MenuBarVertical li` have set width to 8em. If you change width style of these blocks to 100% it should work for you as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for that - it solved the initial problerm but now the sub menu drops off the side of the page when the window is resized to mobile view?

Comment: That's because of your `ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul` has unnecesary percent margin style: `margin: -5% 0 0 95%;`. By removing this or change it's value you should solve your problem ;)